# Text overflow not working in box display with horizontal box-orient

Tags: html, css, qooxdoo

I am using the box display, but I cannot get my text to properly render an ellipsis. Right now the text is just overflowing past the containing element.

HTML:

```
<div class="outer hbox">
  <div class="hbox left-container">
    <div class="label no-wrap box-centered">Col1</div>
  </div>
  <h1 class="label no-wrap">really long title really long title really long title really long title really long title really long title really long title really long title really long title</h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer {
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.hbox {
  -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  box-orient: horizontal;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: box;
}
.left-container {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.no-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
h1 {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/bmclachlin/Sq7Xa/

I've tried wrapping the h1 in a div, changing the h1 to a div, etc., but nothing seems to work. I know I'm probably missing something obvious, any ideas?

Note: This code is being generated from a JavaScript library called qooxdoo, so I don't have the ability to change the structure too much. I can change the h1 to a different element as well as wrap the h1 in a div if I wanted to.

Comment: h1 takes all width, do you have control of css?

Comment: Yup I have control over the css and I can also change the h1 to a different element. I changed the h1 to a div and gave it a width of 100%. The problem now is that the right-container still overflows in Chrome. It looks like it overflows the size of the left-container. In firefox there is no change. I've updated the jsfiddle.

Comment: that was just clue, see updated post, hope that would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `h1` tag is treated like one very long line of text because of `no-wrap` and this is the reason it just takes so long place as the text and overflowing just could not be applied to it. Consider example with:

```
.no-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Sq7Xa/13/

so the `h1` forced to take full width of parent container and overflow appied

UPD: little bit closer workaround would be to define actual width to both elements, with small invasion to your code that could looks like http://jsfiddle.net/Sq7Xa/15/, note there is still 2px are inconsistency because of borders around the `h1`

if you really need keep that border, there is couple workarounds with that:

1. one using `box-sizing: border-box;` property to `h1` http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing

   ```
   h1 {
     box-sizing: border-box;
     border: 1px solid green;
     width: 80%;
   }
   ```
2. the other one would require another `div` into `h1` sample code http://jsfiddle.net/Sq7Xa/18/

But yet, I have feeling that things could be done simpler with revising code, especially `display: box;` which at my point bit extra.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I don't mind putting a percentage for the children inside the div, but I'd prefer not to. I found a way that I don't have to by using box-flex on the right container. Also, instead of using an h1 I updated it to a div. See my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bmclachlin/Sq7Xa/

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll let you know how it goes when I implement the change.

Comment: you are welcome, your last fiddle looks good in Chrome but not in IEs even IE10. Though admit it is cutting edge, if there is no needs support MS guys you are good set:)

Comment: We are making a mobile version of our application using qooxdoo + phonegap. I'm not too worried about IE as long as android, ios and bb10 work correctly ;)